Can I get Vite to exclude certain lines of code using the 'dropLabels' option?
I'm using Vite to bundle my Vue.js application, and I noticed that esbuild has an interesting option called "Drop Labels" which provides an easy way to exclude debugging code from your production bundle.
Here's an example:
DEV: console.log('This should only show in development.');

Here's what I've tried in vite.config.js:
export default defineConfig({
  ...
  esbuild: {
    dropLabels: ['DEV'],
  }
})

This option seems to be being processed (because if I specify a string instead of an array, I get an error), but the console.log still appears in the bundle.
Interestingly, when I enable the drop option, like the following:
esbuild: {
  drop: ['console'],
  dropLabels: ['DEV'],
}

...the console.log finally disappears, but what if I don't want to remove all console.log's, but only specific ones?
Could it be that the DEV: label is being stripped out by some other optimizer before reaching esbuild?
To reproduce this, here's a simple StackBlitz that demonstrates it:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-4uczvd?file=src%2Fmain.js,vite.config.js&terminal=dev
(The dev server will run by default, and you can view the console.log's by opening your browser dev tools. To run a production build, quit the dev server with Q, ENTER and then type npm run build && cat dist/assets/index*.js and you will see the production bundle JS output.)

Sounds like "dropLabels" isn't really working.

It works for me. Actually, it even drops the labeled line in dev mode. Could you post a full minimal example that reproduces your issue?

@xuhdev - I've added a link to a StackBlitz environment that reproduces the issue. Have you configured yours differently?

@AlexanderNenashev - Are you sure that esbuild is only used in dev mode? If so, why does the drop option work correctly when performing npm run build to create a production bundle?

esbuild by default is only applied to ts, tsx, jsx files. By renaming the file name from main.js to main.ts, the DEV label takes effects.

Thanks for the suggestion @xuhdev, however if esbuild is not applied to .js files, then why does the drop: ['console'] option work? That seems counter-intuitive.

@SimonE. I don't know, overall the options around esbuild in vite are a bit buggy to me. For example, I haven't been successful to include the js file via esbuild.include, like the referenced doc suggests. I would recommend filing a bug at https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues
